# What are n bins and patches in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I read this in the matplotlib tutorial:

`n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)`

I am wondering what are n, bins, and patches

Answer (score 17):

I was going to suggest [reading the docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) but this provides no extra explanation although I still advise you have a look.

- `n`: is the number of counts in each bin of the histogram
- `bins`: is the left hand edge of each bin
- `patches`is the individual patches used to create the histogram, e.g a collection of rectangles

The patches can be used to change the properties of individual bars as in [these examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html). Here is a simple example of its use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.normal(size=100)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x)

plt.setp(patches[0], 'facecolor', 'g')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In general the `n` and `bins` are used for subsequent data analysis as in [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/api/histogram_demo.html)

Comment: Could you put in a quick PR at add that to the `hist` docstring?